# What's Microsoft's .Net tool which bundles assemblies for different technologies called?

Tags: .net

I'm sure I heard in one of the Build conference videos about a CTP of a product that generates assemblies that can be used in different types of .Net products e.g. Phone and Silverlight.

I've for the life of me forgotten what they've called it and I can't conjure up the correct Googling terms. I've been trying for hours. Anyone know what I'm on about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was the Portable Class Libraries I was after.

Comment: +1 sorry I misread the question!

Answer (score 1):

You can use

- [ilmerge.exe](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=22914587-B4AD-4EAE-87CF-B14AE6A939B0&displaylang=en)

and on mono there is a great number of related tools:

- mono Cecil is a roundtrip capable IL assembly reader.writer

- MonoMerge is based on it: http://evain.net/blog/articles/2006/11/06/an-introduction-to-mono-merge
- IL-Repack is an opensource tools based on it http://code.google.com/p/il-repack/:

> ILRepack is meant at replacing ILMerge / Mono.Merge
>
> The former being closed-source, impossible to customize, slow, resource consuming and many more. The later being deprecated, unsupported, and based on an old version of Mono.Cecil.

More geared towards dependency reduction, ahead-of-time compilation (think NGen.exe) and statical linking (think: impossible with Microsoft):

- mkbundle
- monolinker

Comment: I'm not sure how that relates to the question. How does IL help with multi targeting an assembly? It merges assemblies.